# How to read connection string from Azure app configuration?

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-app-configuration

Step 1:I have the below app configuration key set up in azure portal:

```
KEY: ABC:EmployeeProfile:AzureStorage:ConnectionString
Value: MyAzureStorageConnectionString
```

Now I am using .Net Core5.0 web api.
Step 2.In my Program.cs, I have:

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost
                .CreateDefaultBuilder()
                .UseConfiguration(configuration)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseSerilog();

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
           Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
               .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
               {
                   webBuilder.ConfigureAppConfiguration(config =>
                   {
                       var settings = config.Build();
                       var connection = settings["AppConfiguration:ConnectionString"];
                       config.AddAzureAppConfiguration(connection);
                   });
                   webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
               });
```

Step 3.In my appsettings.json file, I have the below:

```
 "AppConfiguration": {
    "ConnectionString": "blabla"
  },
```

Step 4: trying to access the same like below

```
var test = ConfigurationExtensions.GetConnectionString(_configuration, "ABC:EmployeeProfile:AzureStorage:ConnectionString");
```

But, it is returning null, any clue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Nah, got it:
In step 4:

```
var storageConnectionString = _configuration.GetValue<string>("ABC:EmployeeProfile:AzureStorage:ConnectionString");
```

That will do; no need to use `ConfigurationExtensions` class.
Although, there could be benefits of using it in some use cases.